# WolframAlpha wrong(?) graph

Tags: graphing-functions, wolfram-alpha

I had a question to plot a graph of

> $\space \space\LARGE y=x^{x^{x^{x^{...}}}}$

Which (according to me) is equivalent to

$\large y=x^y \Rightarrow y^{\frac{1}{y}}=x$

---

So i plotted them in my copy (by taking dozens of different values of y to get x)

To check my graph i plotted them in both "DESMOS" and "WOLFRAMALPHA"

---

The Results:

**Desmos:** (*Same as mine!*) [image: desmos]

> **WolframAlpha:** [image: WA]
>
> **Why does the graph in the case of WolframAlpha going towards $-x$-axis?**

Comment: They're both correct... although the "y-axis" in your W|A picture is not actually the y-axis, it is actually the vertical line x=1.381. Try zooming in and out on the frame in the W|A picture and you will see.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Wolfram Alpha one doesn't seem to start at $ x=0 $ (look at the numbers at the bottom).

Comment: yeah ! But in the desmos it starts $\Tiny just$ above $0$ and kind of *grazes* the y-axis before reaching $0. ...$

Comment: So...which is the right one?

Comment: I think they're both right, Wolfram Alpha is just giving the graph for a small range of x values (around 1.4), Desmos is plotting it starting at x=0. The Wolfram Alpha curve looks exaggerated because it's only taking a narrow range of x values.

Comment: Why going negative then (after $y=5$) ?

Comment: @NeilRoy Its not going negative, its just going to $x<1.4$

Comment: @VladimirLenin Oh ya sorry!

Comment: @NeilRoy:  it is not going negative.  The $y$ axis is not drawn crossing the $x$ axis at $0$. It is hard to read in the figure you post, but it looks like it crosses at $1.38$

Comment: x is not negative after y=5. You're reading the graph wrong. x is about 1.381 where the x and y axes meet on the Wolfram Alpha graph.

Comment: @NeilRoy If you are still not convinced, see this graph by wolfram, from 0 to 3

http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y%5E%281%2Fy%29%3Dx%2C+plot+from+x%3D0+to+3%2Cy%3D0+to+25

Answer (score 2):

*This is not an answer but it is too long for a comment.*

If you are concerned by the plot of $y$ as a function of $x$ such that $\space y^{1/y}=x$, it means that $$y=-\dfrac{W(-\log (x))}{\log (x)}$$ where appears Lambert function.

In the real domain, $x$ must be positive and function $W(a)$ is only defines if $a \geq -\frac 1e$ which makes $0 < x \leq e^{\frac{1}{e}}\approx 1.44467$ and $y$ varies between $0$ and $e$. At both ends, the tangent to the curves is vertical.

May I suggest you ask Wolfram Alpha to plot the equation I wrote and I suppose that you will get something similar to what you obtained with your own plot.

Comment: Yeah i did that ... and the result seems to be different (?) [link: http://goo.gl/vOmMmv ]

Comment: I think that the plot from WA is made very complicated because it also considers the complex parts. I confirm that what you obtained by yourself is excatly what I get using Lambert function as I wrote it.

Comment: If you want a cleaner (Real part) >>> http://goo.gl/lOVCpG

Comment: You have the real part of a complex number if $x<0$. For example $$y(-1)=\frac{i W(-i \pi )}{\pi }\approx 0.266037+ 0.29429 i$$ You must consider only the part where $y$ is a real.

Answer (score 2):

**Tip of the day:** You can focus in on a region by typing into WolframAlpha:

`Plot[y^(1/y) == x, {x, 0, 5}]`

`Plot[y^(1/y) == x, {x, 0, 1.5}]`

`Plot[y^(1/y) == x, {x, 1, 1.5}, {y, 1, 20}]`

... and so forth.